# How to recover from a backup file

Tags: auto-save, backup, recover

I can recover a file from an *auto-save* via `M-x recover-this-file`. So far so good.

But how can I recover a file from it's last backup (if, of course, I have switched backups on)?

Answer (score 1):

For that, I use https://github.com/lewang/backup-walker.

```
(autoload 'backup-walker-start "backup-walker" "" t)
```